# How to automatically adjust subfigure width to textwidth?

Tags: floats, subcaption

Code where I have to manually adjust subfigure textwidth (here `.95\textwidth`) each time, but I would like do it automatically; you can use any enough big input image

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.95\textwidth}
        \adjustbox{trim=0 .45\height{} 0 0, clip, width=1\textwidth}
        {\includegraphics[page=1]{{P100C1}.pdf}}
    \caption{P100 C1.}
    \end{subfigure}

     \begin{subfigure}{.95\textwidth}
        \adjustbox{trim=0 .45\height{} 0 0, clip, width=1\textwidth}
        {\includegraphics[page=1]{{P100C1}.pdf}}
    \caption{P100 C2.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Descriptive statistics of two lorem ipsun on long recordings lorem ipsun dataabess lorem ipsun lorem ipsun.}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Input image can be downloaded from Google Drive Share [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_TQai5bck2FZEFLVUtQWWFJQzQ/view?usp=sharing) or other hosting service [here](http://docdro.id/CscLvlR) made by NCSS Statistics.

Output

```
LaTeX Warning: Float too large for page by 11.50876pt on input line 1950.
```

### Testing David and Arash's proposals

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[a]{.85\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[page=2,width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{P100C1.pdf}
\caption{P100 C1.}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{.85\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[page=2,width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{P100C2.pdf}
\caption{P100 C2.}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Descriptive statistics of lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem.}
\end{figure}
```

Output: no warning

Automatic approach would be nice.

TeXLive: 2016
OS: Debian 8.5

Comment: your question is completely unclear, you ask about the horizontal width of the subfigures (why do you use .95 not the full width)? but the images you include are not scaled at all so the subfigure width is fairly arbitrary, but then you show a warning about _vertical_ extent of the figure.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do so can not suggest a better way. using only 95% of the width just looks odd, the `%` between the two subfigures looks odd (forcing tex to try to put them both on the same line) and the extra braces  before the `.pdf` only work by accident. If the two images are too large to fit on a page you need to scale them, eg scale them both to have height .4\textheight.

Comment: Your question is also not clear to me.  Maybe it helps if you include graphics with `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{P100C2}` and set the width with `\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}`.  Now the graphic is scaled to the `0.45\textwidth`.

Comment: why are you constraining the  width of the subfigures ? There is no point at all in doing that, and since your size warning was about the _height_ of the figures why are you scaling their width?  Since you haven't provided any code anyone can run. as I suggested above you should be scaling the height.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added an example input pdf document in the body.

Comment: Instead of using the `subfigure` environment one could use `\subcaptionbox` which automatically is as width as its contents.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt Can it offer any benefit against the current approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your modified write-up suggests that what you really need to do is to constrain the *height* of the graphs. Assuming your captions aren't overly long, setting the option `height=0.4\textheight` may work for you.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[page=2,width=0.85\textwidth,
                    height=0.4\textheight,
                    keepaspectratio]{P100C1.pdf}
\caption{P100 C1.}
\end{subfigure}

\bigskip
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[page=2,width=0.85\textwidth,
                    height=0.4\textheight,
                    keepaspectratio]{P100C2.pdf}
\caption{P100 C2.}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Descriptive statistics of lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```